# Graphing function level curves with complex values

Tags: complex-analysis, math-software

I need to graph the contour lines of the [following](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sFqXkP6BzYntTfOwlMjKjVWTfZk0YrhZ/view) functions with complex values, I have tried it in Matlab, but the truth is I am new to the subject, can you help me please or do you know of any software where it can be done easily?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't speak Spanish, but I would guess that the question is asking you to graph the *real part* of the complex function. You are therefore plotting a real-valued function, from what is essentially $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: yes, what they have asked me is to graph the contour lines of the real part of that function, the problem i have is that this function goes from $\mathbb{R^3}-> \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Maybe try something along these lines: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/490769-how-to-i-plot-3d-level-surfaces-of-this-4d-function I'm not good with Matlab.

Comment: Thanks so much!